# Facebook Graph API - Get Ad Spent based on Date Range

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the Ad Spent for an AD Account based on Dates Range Interval.

I can get it for today or for yesterday but couldnt find a way to get it for a specific interval. I've tried the date_preset parameter but it works only for yesterday/today. Also tried with time_range. Couldnt figure it out.

curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/act_{ad_account_id}/insights?fields=spend&access_token={access_token}&date_preset=today"

Solved!

The parameters used for date range are the following:

time_range[since]=2018-10-20&time_range[until]=2018-10-25

Comment: you should use the`time_range` as described in the [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

The parameters used for date range are the following:

time_range[since]=2018-10-20&time_range[until]=2018-10-25